# ASP.Net Web API with Digest Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, digest-authentication

I have written a bunch of restful ASP.Net Web API and I want to authenticate some of the API. I have gone with Digest Authentication implementation from [here](http://www.tomdupont.net/2014/08/basic-and-digest-mixed-authentication.html)

Also I have referred demo code from [here](https://github.com/tdupont750/DigestAuthDemo)

I have understood the code a bit but I have no idea where and how do I connect my existing database for getting data from customer table. If anyone has information regarding how to achieve this then please share.

Following are some methods for authentication:

DigestAuthorizationFilterAttributeBase.cs

```
protected override string GetAuthenticatedUser(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
        if (auth == null || auth.Scheme != Scheme)
            return null;

        var header = DigestHeader.Create(
            actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter, 
            actionContext.Request.Method.Method);

        if (!DigestNonce.IsValid(header.Nonce, header.NounceCounter))
        { 
            return null;
        }
               var password = GetPassword(header.UserName);

            var hash1 = String.Format(
            "{0}:{1}:{2}",
            header.UserName,
            header.Realm,
            password).ToMd5Hash();

            var hash2 = String.Format(
                "{0}:{1}",
                header.Method,
                header.Uri).ToMd5Hash();

            var computedResponse = String.Format(
                "{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}",
                hash1,
                header.Nonce,
                header.NounceCounter,
                header.Cnonce,
                "auth",
                hash2).ToMd5Hash();

            return header.Response.Equals(computedResponse, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                ? header.UserName
                : null;

    }
```

DigestAuthorizationFilterAttribute.cs

```
    public DigestAuthorizationFilterAttribute(bool issueChallenge = true) : base(issueChallenge)
    {

    }

    protected override bool IsUserAuthorized(string userName)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override string GetPassword(string userName)
    {
        return userName;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One example would be in the following method:

```
protected override bool IsUserAuthorized(string userName)
{
    return true;
}
```

You could do something roughly similar to:

```
protected override bool IsUserAuthorized(string userName)
{
    var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.username = userName);
    if(user.Any())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You would also need to check if the password is valid. But you get the idea.

Hope this helped.